# Python-SocketIO fails with "Unsupported upgrade request" possibly a faulty Nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io, python-socketio

I am using the socket.io javascript client with version:

`"socket.io-client": "^3.1.2",`

And on the python side  :

```
python-engineio==4.1.0
python-socketio==5.0.4
uvicorn==0.13.4
```

The connection attemps are failing with the return

`400:  "Unsupported upgrade request."`

The request sent from the browser are:

curl 'http://localhost:9004/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NbcVN2X' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' 
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' 
-H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"' 
-H 'Accept: */*' 
-H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' 
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' 
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' 
-H 'Referer: http://localhost:9004/' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7' 
--compressed

I have an Nginx instance in the middle, and I suspect it is causing the problem, because if I send the same CURL request directly to the python server (instead of through Nginx), I get the response :

`0{"sid":"3PAgAppFeoBEiwAsAAAG","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingTimeout":20000,"pingInterval":25000}`

On the JavaScript (socket.io) client side, the connection is made with:

`const socket = io(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + "/drypipe")`

Here are my Nginx rules:

```
    location /socket.io {

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass   $scheme://127.0.0.1:5000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /sockjs-node {

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass   $scheme://127.0.0.1:5000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /drypipe {

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass   $scheme://127.0.0.1:5000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2209

```
python3 -m pip uninstall uvicorn
python3 -m pip install uvicorn[standard]
```